# How to access the properties of a generically defined object?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have the following code. (Designed to open a viewmodel from code).

```
private void OpenView<viewType,viewModelType> (object parameters) {

        //STEP 1. CREATE THE VIEW
        var view = (viewType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(viewType));            

        //STEP 2. SET THE DATACONTEXT
        var viewModel = (viewModelType)view.DataContext;            

        //STEP 3. OPEN THE WINDOW AND WAIT UNTIL MANUALLY CLOSED            
        TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        window.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(view);
        window.Activate();
        window.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

The compiler gives me the following error;

> Error CS1061  'viewType' does not contain a definition for
>   'DataContext' and no extension method 'DataContext' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'viewType' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I cannot access the DataContext in step 2 because I presume the compiler does not know what type the view variable is. Can anyone tell me how I can tell the compiler what type the view variable is? and if that is not possible. How to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two real solutions here.

1. `viewType` is always the same type: So don't make it generic.
2. `viewType` always inherits from the same base class or implements a common interface. For example, it is always a [`FrameworkElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the [`DataContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) property. If that's the case, you can constrain the generic type to that class:

   ```
   private void OpenView<TViewType, TViewModelType>(object parameters)
       where viewType : FrameworkElement // This is the magic sauce
   {
       var view = (TViewType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TViewType));            

       // Now we can access the DataContext
       var viewModel = (TViewModelType)view.DataContext;  

       //snip
   }
   ```

PS It's pretty common practice to prefix generic types with `T`

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thank you. I shall follow the common practice and prefix with T. This makes sense!